# Is it possible to execute a query while in a mutation?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I have written a mutation that is triggered on the front end, and I have built a custom email system for django that uses gql to query for the exact context needed. In the mutation, it is possible to trigger an email. However, when this happens, both the mutation and the query stall. My solution until now has been to push the email trigger into a task, which seems to work, but is not ideal. Any ideas on how I can get this to work without needing a task?

```py
# Super simplified example

class MyEmail(CustomEmailClass):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing

    @cached_property
    def context(self):
        return schema.execute_query(query, variable_values={
            'thingId': self.thing.id,
        )

    def send(self):
        # get templates and do other things
        # ...
        EmailMultiAlternatives(
            body=plaintext_template.render(self.context),
            **kwargs).send()

class MyMutation(relay.ClientIdMutation):
    class Input:
        id = ID()

    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, input, context, info):
        # do things here
        # ...
        MyEmail(thing=instance).send()
        return MyMutation(instance=instance)
```